# Can not solve Unmet dependencies while installing or upgrading any packages

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

When I run from the terminal
 `sudo apt upgrade`

But I have run these commads before I encounter this issue:

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml php7.0-bcmath php7.0-mbstring -y
sudo wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix- 
release/zabbix-release_3.2-1+xenial_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i zabbix-release_3.2-1+xenial_all.deb
sudo apt-get install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php
sudo apt update -y
```

I have the following unmet dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsnmp30 : Depends: libsnmp-base but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I run the following commands from terminal to fix this issue but no luck:

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
 sudo apt-cache search libsnmp*
 sudo apt-get install snmpd libsnmp30 libsnmp-base
 sudo rm -f  /var/cache/apt/archives/libsnmp-base_5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1_all.deb
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

The output of  `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
 Unpacking libsnmp-base (5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1) ...
 dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsnmp-base_5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man5/snmpd.internal.5.gz', which is 
 also in package net-snmp 5.4.2.1-9.12
 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
 Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsnmp-base_5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1_all.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could someone give me some tips/hints to fix this issue? I am running on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS
I have googled for some time but did not find a solution yet.
The output of `sudo apt-cache policy net-snmp`:

```
net-snmp:
  Installed: 5.4.2.1-9.12
  Candidate: 5.4.2.1-9.12
  Version table:
 *** 5.4.2.1-9.12 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy net-snmp` the question.

Comment: @N0rbert updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem on clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

You should install the problematic package manually with

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all \
/var/cache/apt/archives/libsnmp-base_5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1_all.deb
```

and then remove locally installed `net-snmp` package with:

```
sudo apt-get purge net-snmp
```

and then resume installation

```
sudo apt-get install snmpd libsnmp30 libsnmp-base
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: When I tried to remove any packages I get the same dependencies problem as mentioned in the questions section. Those options I tried before posting the questions  though

Comment: OK, let's use other method. Let's force installation of problematic package:     `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libsnmp-base_5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4.1_all.deb`. Then follow my answer.

Comment: Cool fixed the issue

Comment: update your answer with the command you have on the comment section

Comment: Doing a dist-upgrade not a good idea though. I wont do that

Comment: Great, that it works. Also please note that [`apt-get dist-upgrade`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) is not equal to [`do-release-upgrade`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html) - you will stay on 16.04 LTS, but your packages will be upgraded to the latest set of package dependencies.